How to filter on an array in meilisearch?
I'm using Meilisearch with Laravel Scout on Laravel 10.
In my index, I store an array of denied_categories as an array of integers which are ids of categories like this :


In my frontend I would like to filter with this parameter by sending an array of integers and do not display the items which have one or more id in common.
I was thinking about storing theses ids as a chain of characters separated by a comma and use a regex but Meilisearch doesn't provide this.
I tried to use the IN filter but it works the other way.
Do someone have any idea on how to do it ?

you have all these conditions, you can use the != or the NOT to "not display the items"

@francisco Yes I know but I can't filter on an array from my index. I have other conditions that works well on strings or integers for example but I can't find how to filter in an array like a NOT CONTAINS

try like 'field NOT IN('. implode(',',$array) .')' or put some code so I can help u.
